# remove lines that do not match specific digits in list file using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to remove the lines in `file` that do not match the digits after the `NM_` but before the `.` in `$2` of `list`.  Thank you :).

**file**

```
204 NM_003852   chr7    +   138145078   138270332   138145293   
204 NM_015905   chr7    +   138145078   138270332   138145293
```

**list**

```
TRIM24 NM_015905.2
```

**awk**

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{ sub(/\r/, "") } ; NR==FNR { N=$2 ; sub(/\..*/, "", $2); A[$2]=N; next } ; $2 in A { $2=A[$2] } 1' list file > out
```

**current output**

```
204 NM_003852   chr7    +   138145078   138270332   138145293   
204 NM_015905.2 chr7    +   138145078   138270332   138145293
```

**desired output** (line 1 removed as that is the line that does not match)

```
204 NM_015905.2 chr7    +   138145078   138270332   138145293
```

Comment: My apologies, I was trying to be complete with my data, but see your point. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{split($2,f2,".");a[f2[1]];next} $2 in a' list file
```

Comment: So just so I understand `$2` of `list` is split on the `.` and then matched to `file`. The portion after the split is put into the `a[f2]` array and when a match is found in `file` that array is placed after the `$2` match and the `NR==FNR` tells `awk` to keep only the matching line? I hope I got it... as a scientist I try my best. Thank you very much :).

Comment: Correct.  After this much exposure I guess you got the gist of it.  `f2[1]` is first part of the split field, which is the key for the second file lookup.  We keep these keys in the `a` array and lookup in the second file processing, if found it's printed out (missing explicit statement but default action).

Comment: Thank you very much, it is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[ .]' 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}$2 in a' list file
204 NM_015905   chr7    +   138145078   138270332   138145293
```

Comment: The `awk` uses the `.` to separate each `$2` value, stores that in key `a` and uses that key to look for a match in `file`. Only the matching line is keep by using `NR==FNR`. This is how I understand it and as I am still learning, may be missing something. Thank you :).

Comment: @Rakete1111 no, it wouldn't. This is absolutely basic awk and anyone who doesn't understand it will get far more out of learning where the man page is and glancing at that than me spoon-feeding them just these instructions (which btw occur in thousands of other answers), and they can always ask questions or post their interpretation for verification as the OP did.

Comment: @Chris - not sure if it's what you meant but the `NR==FNR` is what separates populating vs testing of the array. The condition `NR==FNR` is only true while reading the first file so that test combined with the `next` ensures the rest of the code populates the array for the first file and tests it for the 2nd file.

Comment: It's not basic for me (I never use `awk` :) But fine, point taken. I'll do better next time :)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Ed Morton :)